# Summarizing data

Tags: r, dataframe, nested

My data frame called “data” needs to be arranged such that entries before 1/5 will be marked as 1/5 after they have been grouped by ID and Country. Entries after 1/5 will have the same date or be  marked as earlier date if there are more than one entry for the same ID and country with different dates.

Part of my data frame (called "data"):

```
CreatedDate Country Alt. ItemId Qty
19-05-2014  Sweden  SFND-023903 30
13-05-2014  Norway  SFND-023903 10
23-05-2014  Norway  SFND-023903 20
07-04-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   1440
28-04-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   2400
22-04-2014  Norway  SN-073628   40
05-05-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   840
23-05-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   1559
23-05-2014  Norway  SN-073628   40
```

I want the result like this:

```
CreatedDate Country Alt. ItemId Qty
19-05-2014  Sweden  SFND-023903 30
13-05-2014  Norway  SFND-023903 30
01-05-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   3840
01-05-2014  Norway  SN-073628   40
05-05-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   2399
23-05-2014  Norway  SN-073628   40
```

My current code:

```
d1 <- data%.% 
  mutate(CreatedDate=as.Date(CreatedDate),format="%d-%m-%Y")%.% 
  filter(CreatedDate>=as.Date("2014-05-01"))%.%
  group_by(Alt..ItemId, Country)%.% 
  summarize(Qty=sum(Qty),CreatedDate=min(CreatedDate))

d2 <- data%.% 
  mutate(CreatedDate=as.Date(CreatedDate),format="%d-%m-%Y")%.% 
  filter(CreatedDate<=as.Date("2014-05-01"))%.%
  group_by(Alt..ItemId, Country)%.% 
  summarize(Qty=sum(Qty),CreatedDate=as.Date("2014-05-01"))

d <- rbind(d1,d2)
d <- d[order(d$Alt..ItemId,d$CreatedDate),]
```

How can I combine the two date arguments in d1 and d2 into one code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a dplyr client but here one way to do it:

```
ddt <- read.table(text='CreatedDate Country ItemId Qty
19-05-2014  Sweden  SFND-023903 30
13-05-2014  Norway  SFND-023903 10
23-05-2014  Norway  SFND-023903 20
07-04-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   1440
28-04-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   2400
22-04-2014  Norway  SN-073628   40
05-05-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   840
23-05-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   1559
23-05-2014  Norway  SN-073628   40',header=TRUE)

ddt$CreatedDate <-  as.Date(ddt$CreatedDate,format="%d-%m-%Y")


library(dplyr)
ddt%.% 
  mutate(flag = CreatedDate > as.Date("2014-05-01"))%.%
  group_by(ItemId, Country,flag)%.% 
  summarize(Qty=sum(Qty),
            CreatedDate=if(all(!flag))as.Date("2014-05-01") 
            else min(CreatedDate))

#   ItemId       Country  flag  Qty CreatedDate
# 1 SFND-023903  Norway  TRUE   30  2014-05-13
# 2 SFND-023903  Sweden  TRUE   30  2014-05-19
# 3   SN-073628  Norway FALSE   40  2014-05-01
# 4   SN-073628  Norway  TRUE   40  2014-05-23
# 5   SN-073628  Sweden FALSE 3840  2014-05-01
# 6   SN-073628  Sweden  TRUE 2399  2014-05-05
```

Comment: I couldn't get the column flag shown. I've received this error message: "Error in if (all(!flag)) as.Date("2014-05-01") else min(CreatedDate) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Comment: @user3206981 I copy all my code (even data creation) , copy and paste it should work. For your information , I just changed one  column name to remove annoying  spaces...

Comment: I did copy your code, but my R doesn't seem to cooperate, same error.  The small changes I made is: changing from "ddt" to "data" because that is what my dataframe is called, and "ItemId" to "Alt..ItemId" because that is the column header. Did the changes I made affect the result?

Comment: Get the point :-) ...I need to re-read my data as "read.table" and NOT "read.csv". Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

data <- read.table(text="CreatedDate Country Alt.ItemId Qty
19-05-2014  Sweden  SFND-023903 30
13-05-2014  Norway  SFND-023903 10
23-05-2014  Norway  SFND-023903 20
07-04-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   1440
28-04-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   2400
22-04-2014  Norway  SN-073628   40
05-05-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   840
23-05-2014  Sweden  SN-073628   1559
23-05-2014  Norway  SN-073628   40",header=T)

setDT(data)
```

Now we need to correct the date format:

```
data[,CreatedDate := as.Date(CreatedDate,"%d-%m-%Y")]
```

Next we create a tag on the date:

```
data[,tag := CreatedDate > as.Date("2014-05-01")]
```

Lastly, the query:

```
data[,.SD[,list(
  if(all(tag)) min(CreatedDate) else as.Date("2014-05-01"),sum(Qty))],
by=c("Country","Alt.ItemId","tag")]
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your input. Great to see another way to resolve the issue :-)